# Android hilt injection cycle error with multiple modules referencing a core module

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

We currently have 3 modules: App, Api and Core.
App depends on Api and Core.
Api depends on Core.

In our Core module we have a VersionProvider:

```
class VersionProvider @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context) {
    val versionName = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).versionName

    val versionCode = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).longVersionCode
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).versionCode
    }
}
```

That is injected in classes, both in Api module and App module.

The core module hilt module is defined like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class CoreModule {

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindVersionProvider(
        provider: VersionProvider
    ): VersionProvider
}
```

When compiling we get this error:

> C:\Code\xxx\app\build\generated\hilt\component_sources\development\com\xxx\App_HiltComponents.java:200:
> error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:   public
> abstract static class SingletonC implements App_GeneratedInjector,
> ^
> com.xxx.core.VersionProvider is injected at
> com.xxx.core.hilt.CoreModule.bindVersionProvider(provider)
> com.xxx.core.VersionProvider is injected at
> com.xxx.core.hilt.CoreModule.bindVersionProvider(provider)
> ...
> The cycle is requested via:
> com.xxx.core.VersionProvider is injected at
> com.xxx.api.core.hilt.ApiClientModule.bindNetworkManager(�, versionProvider)
> com.xxx.api.services.helpers.INetworkManager is injected at
> com.xxx.api.core.hilt.ApiClientModule.bindInventoryApi(networkManager)
> com.xxx.api.services.inventory.InventoryApi is injected at
> com.xxx.api.services.inventory.InventoryService(api, �)
> com.xxx.api.services.inventory.InventoryService is injected at
> com.xxx.api.core.hilt.ServiceModule.bindInventoryService(service)
> com.xxx.api.services.inventory.IInventoryService is injected at
> com.xxx.managers.inventory.InventoryManager(inventoryService, �)
> com.xxx.managers.inventory.InventoryManager is injected at
> com.xxx.core.hilt.ManagerModule.bindInventoryManager(manager)
> com.xxx.managers.inventory.IInventoryManager is injected at
> com.xxx.App.inventoryManager
> com.xxx.App is injected at
> com.xxx.App_GeneratedInjector.injectApp(com.xxx.App)   The following other entry points also depend on it:
> dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap()
> [com.xxx.App_HiltComponents.SingletonC ?
> com.xxx.App_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ?
> com.xxx.App_HiltComponents.ViewModelC] 1 error

In the App and API module the Hilt module is defined in the same way e.g.:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApiClientModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun bindNetworkManager(
        settings: ISettings,
        versionProvider: VersionProvider
    ): INetworkManager {
        return NetworkManager(settings, versionProvider)
    }
...
}
```

I think the problem has to do with the fact that VersionProvider is somehow registered mulitple times in the Hilt container as it is referenced both from the App and Api modules.
But I don't know what Hilt configuration I am missing to make it work.
Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the dependency cycle occurs in the `CoreModule`. Try removing this:

```
    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindVersionProvider(
        provider: VersionProvider
    ): VersionProvider
```

And annotating the `VersionProvider` class with `@Singleton`.

Comment: With that I get a KSP error:  Execution failed for task ':api:kspDevelopmentKotlin'. A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard are you sure it's related to the problem in question? You had `bindVersionProvider` depending on `VersionProvider` depending on `bindVersionProvider`.

Comment: It works now with that exact change - tt seems like it was just a clean it was missing, thanks.